# AppleScript dead slow in moving files to folder

Tags: applescript

I'm trying to move a bunch of files into folders, based on the file creation date. Using the script below, the rate of move is about 1 file per second. 64000 files to go.
Script timed out when I tried

```
set myFiles to items of myFolder whose name ends with "jpg"
repeat with aFile in myFiles
```

So now I process file by file and only checking folder existing when the date comparison failed sped up the process only marginally. I've tried the obvious

```
set myDayBuddies to items of myFolder whose creation date is theFileDate
```

but this too, did not help really much. I suspect Finder reads the whole folder content time and time again, creating huge overhead.

What is the proper method of speeding up this any further? In PHP I know I can read entries from a directory stream, one by one.

Script:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set myFolder to choose folder
    set prevDateString to ""
    repeat while true
        try
            set aFile to first item of myFolder whose name ends with "jpg"
            set theFileDate to (the creation date of aFile)
            set theDateString to my composedate(theFileDate)
            if (theDateString is not prevDateString) then
                if not (exists folder ((myFolder & theDateString) as text)) then
                    make new folder at myFolder with properties {name:theDateString}
                end if
                set prevDateString to theDateString
                set destPath to (((myFolder as text) & theDateString) as alias)
            end if
            move aFile to destPath
        on error
            return
        end try
    end repeat
end tell
on composedate(aDate)
    set y to (year of aDate as integer) as string
    set m to (month of aDate as integer) as string
    set d to (day of aDate as integer) as string
    if length of m < 2 then
        set m to "0" & m
    end if
    if length of d < 2 then
        set d to "0" & d
    end if
    set myDateString to y & m & d
    return myDateString
end composedate
```

Comment: learning a new language or diving into Terminal is just a bit too much for speeding it up 8-) I would rather like to learn how to reduce the overhead in Applescript/Finder in the current situation. One thing, while the script is crunching away, is that I have attached a Folder Action to the folder with a similar script, so the new files are stowed away immediately and don't add up.

Comment: Thanks Matt, "current situation" is as in "Applescript", not as in "with 60.000 files left". Your remark on ineffiecient handling of date led to testing for text (files happen to have the date in their file name).Folder actions will clean up new files from now on, crunching on the other 60.000 files will take, well, some time. I had hopes somewhere hidden there would be a 'read file by file from resource' option in Applescript, just like in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

System Events was created to take much of the load off the Finder. The Finder is slow so use system events when possible. I'm not sure how it will perform on a folder with 64000 files but give it a try.

```
set myFolder to choose folder

tell application "System Events"
    set f to files of myFolder whose name extension is "jpg"
end tell
```

And if system events is still too slow then applescript alone isn't appropriate for such a large folder. You'll have to go to using the command line even though you said you don't want to. Something like this should be faster...

```
set myFolder to (choose folder) as text
set jpgFiles to paragraphs of (do shell script "ls " & quoted form of POSIX path of myFolder & " | grep 'jpg$'")

repeat with aFile in jpgFiles
    set filePath to myFolder & aFile
    tell application "System Events"
        set theFileDate to creation date of file filePath
        -- do more stuff
    end tell
end repeat
```